# Moq framework: simulating adding an object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, moq, nullreferenceexception

I have just started out using Moq for unit testing have have run into an issue when trying to add an object to our repo. Basically, we have an interface which represents the structure of our DB. This interface contains additional interfaces that represent the data within that DB, like this:

```
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    IRepository<Order> OrdersRepo { get; }
    IRepository<Customer> CustomerRepo { get; }
    IRepository<Product> ProductsRepo { get; }
}
```

Creating the mock IUnitOfWork is no problem, the issue arises when I attempt to add an order object to the OrdersRepo, like this:

```
[TestClass]
public class OrderTest
{
    private Mock<IUnitOfWork> mockDB = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
    private IUnitOfWork testDB;
    private Order testOrder;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        //Create the test order
        testOrder = new Order();
        testOrder.ID = 123;

        //Setting up the Moq DB
        testDB = mockDB.Object;
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void AddOrder_ValidOrder_OrderAdded()
    {   
        testDB.OrdersRepo.Add(testOrder);
    }
}
```

I keep getting a NullReferenceException when I attempt to add the order. I think this is because the OrdersRepo inside the testDB is an interface. However when I tried to create a mock repo for this I get an error saying that the OrdersRepo is readonly because it is { get; } and not { get; set; }.

Is it possible for me to use Moq to test adding my order object when the repo is only get; and is an interface?

Comment: Looks like you're trying to do too much in a single test. What functionality are you testing? Your DB or OrdersRepo?

Comment: Off topic for answering your question, but a suggestion for better coding practice would be to not expose each of those Repositories from your UnitOfWork. Abstract out what they are being saved to, and only have a method on your UnitOfWork to save each object (or a base of each, and determine inside the method how to save it).

Comment: Just my orders repo, however the real world method takes in the database so this is why I've got the mock of the UnitOfWork

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting NullReferenceException because you haven't setup mock object. If you want to setup only 1 property, use

```
mockDB.SetupProperty(self => self.OrdersRepo);
```

If you want to setup property to use your own enumerable, you can use

```
var collection = <Init collection here>;
mockDB.SetupGet(self => self.OrdersRepo).Returns(collection);
```

Or if you want to setup all properties you can use

```
mockDB.SetupAllProperties();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test your orders repo then you shouldn't need to go through the IUnitOfWork and then mocking the Orders repo basically because that way you are not testing your subject. You should be instantiating your concrete of Orders repo and invoke the Add method that should be publicly accessible. Perhaps you will need to mock your underlying DB client your orders repo is invoking to call the DB, but that's another story.

Hope that helps.